# footnote misplaced on page

Tags: sectioning, footnotes

```
% Chapter 1
\chapter{Task-A} % Main chapter title
\label{Chapter1} % For referencing the chapter elsewhere, use \ref{Chapter1} 
\lhead{Chapter 1. \emph{Task-A}} % This is for the header on each page - perhaps a shortened title
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Task description}

The aim of this task is to implement a new Python class for a combined profile. The class to calculate the section values for the combined profile should be implemented with reference to AoS lectures' description \cite{Ref1}. 

Here, the combined profile is a linked group of standard profiles given in the standard table book of European profiles\footnotemark. So every part of the combined profile comes with it’s set of parameter (like h=height, w=width, t=thickness and so on). Our combined profile therefor is the aggregation of all this profile parameters. 

The aim is to compare the result of the thin walled approximation with the exact values of the profile’s area and moment of inertia. To do this, the exact values should be calculated in a testable form using the exact values of the single profiles from the table book.
The results should be discussed and evaluated. 
\\\vspace{2.5 cm}\footnotetext{Warmgewalzter rundkantiger U-Stahl, DIN 1026 (10.63) and DIN EN 10025 - s.458}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{j} 
    \subsection{m}
        \subsubsection{k}
```

[image: The <code>main</code> execution file][image: the output file]

I am using `\pagestyle{fancy}` in my code. Also the `.cls` file contains

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
```

Does it cause this problem? And if I want to continue my next subsection below to last paragraph on same page, how can I do that?

Solution or further reference are also appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hey Christian Hupfer. The code is quite big. Can you suggest how could I send you for reference and further your suggestion?

Comment: it's really not clear what the problem is here, although if i had to guess, i would guess that the footnote is higher on the page than expected.  since we don't know what document class you're using, we're just guessing.  if you really can't provide a full code example, identifying the class and giving a more detailed description of *why* what you're seeing is a problem would at least provide a better basis for guessing.

Comment: @Vishal-vp Thanks for the code. But it'd be better if you posted the actual code (not a picture of it) :D After pasting, select the code and click the `{}` icon (next to the image upload icon).

Comment: I see nothing strange; footnotes are set at the footer.

Comment: The idea is not that you send your big original document but that you generate a small one-page example that shows the problem that you post into the question.Posting code that people can not run doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Footnotes seem to work as intended. When you load the KOMA-class `scrextend` you can use `\deffootnote` to define the footnote space. Here's an example on how to use it:

> \deffootnote[.5em]{0em}{1.5em}{\makebox[.5em][l]{\textsuperscript{\bf \thefootnotemark}}}

[(source)](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=23575)

Comment: Thanks @JonasDralle. It's really good solution. Perhaps I found my error while writing in next `\section{j}`. Since I haven't written anything in that section, LaTex by default placed the section on next page. And before I came to know this, I tried your suggested method and it works great. Thanks.